# React Native: Button at the right end of of Text

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

React Native learner here.
I am trying to show the suggestions as below:

```
             <TouchableOpacity
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                  flexDirection: 'row',
                  flexWrap: 'wrap',
                }}
                onPress={() => {
                  setSelectedValue(item);
                  setFilteredFilms([]);
                }}>
                <View>
                  <Text style={styles.itemText}>{item.title}</Text>
                  <Button
                    title={'Click'}
                    style={{
                      backgroundColor: 'green',

                      right: 0,
                      paddingRight: 0,
                      marginRight: 0,
                    }}></Button>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>


...
itemText: {
    fontSize: 15,
    paddingTop: 5,
    paddingBottom: 5,
    margin: 2,
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
  },
  infoText: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
```

Output looks like below:

[image]

I want my suggestion's `Text` in the left side, while `Click` button always at the right side fixed with fixed length.
Text and Button region shouldn't overlap each other.

Any help or guidance about how to do it. Highly appreciated !!

P.S.: With `style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}` in `<View>` my Buttons in Suggestion box get pushed to right side and not visible as below:

[image]

I expect something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use flexDirection:'row' for inner View which contain the Text and the Button

```
  <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          flexDirection: 'row',
          flexWrap: 'wrap',
          justifyContent: 'space-between',
        }}
        onPress={() => {}}>
        <Text style={{ maxWidth: '90%' }}>
          {item.title}
        </Text>
        <View>
          <Text style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            Click
          </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Using `style={{flexDirection:'row'}}` in `View` as suggested just pushes Click Button out of suggestion box visible area.

Comment: What is the suggestion box here ?

Comment: Suggestion box means the drop down that shows suggestions based on autocomplete. Please see my edited question.

Comment: In that case you have to give a fixed width for the container or the text

Comment: @OmSao why do you have a button inside the touchableopacity ? you are not using the onpress of that as well, better use a text and style it :)

Comment: To simplify the code for posting here, I removed `onPress`. But, yes you are right, inside `TouchableOpacity`, there is no point to put `Button`. So, I can replace it with `View`. And the question remains the same. How to put a text or button at the right end. Please see my question again, to see what I expect :(

Comment: Can i know the styles.itemText ? i can fix this :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222763/discussion-between-om-sao-and-guruparan-giritharan).

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to look at : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-read-more-text

this will help you get through it.